# Add effects to an image dynamically in php

Tags: php, php-gd

I want to add a small functionality to my site wherein a user can upload his pic and then on selecting a specific color(basically on clicking something) a splash effect of that color gets added to that image.

The user should then get an option to save that image.

Is it possible using the php GD library? Any helpful comments are welcome.

Edit: What if i create the images for these effects? how can i overlay them on the user's pic and then offer the complete image as a download?

Comment: please describe what a "spash effect" is...

Comment: hmmm..it would be just like how ur pic will look like if someone jabbed a paintbrush full of color at it...basically an airbrush kind of effect for a particular color....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to create the effect in another image and just use PHPs GDlib to copy that image on the image uploaded by the user and change the color.

You can use `imagecopy` or `imagecopyresized` or `imagecopyresampled`. Depending on the image you are using you could for example use `imagecolorset` to change the color of the effect.

The full list of PHPs image functions is in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use of the GD library might work here, but this is something that ImageMagick was built for.  I'd look into using that, as it's almost as ubiquitous.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the original image as a background image, and add on top of that a full sized fill of a colour at a reduced opacity.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocatealpha.php